Problemas con la libreria de Laravel Octane
quisiera comentarles un caso que estoy experimentando, tengo una aplicación de laravel dentro de un contenedor de docker, y por una extraña razón me empezo a generar unos archivos core.345, core.356... dentro de la carpeta vendor del proyecto y este con con el tiempo pasa los días va creando y ocupando mucho espacio y ha hecho que el contenedor crezca de tamaño. estube invetigando y la libreria Octane es la que esta creando esos archivos, no se si alguien ha tenido este problema y me podria ayudar a como darle solución.


ok imagino que eso te esta pasando en desarrollo... esos archivo se crean cada vez que te sale un error o se bloquea la ejecucion... verifica el contenido ... creo que los podes borrar todos ... ha y verifica el log de actividades de tu php a ver si hay warnign errores que no salen a simple vista
